# How do I generate a color screen for the duration of an MP3 in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have successfully generated a blue screen to add to an mp3. But, I have always needed to include the length of the clip to match the mp3. When I don't include a timecode it continues to generate footage until I cancel the command.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=blue:s=1920x1080 -i input.mp3 -t 00:02:08 output.mp4
```

How do I specify that I only want color generated during the length of the mp3 that I am adding?

```
ffmpeg -i <.jpg> -i <.mp3>
```

This worked too but I don't want to rely on a jpeg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-shortest`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=blue:s=1920x1080 -i input.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I kept getting waveform posts while trying to figure this out.